# Templates do not compile after migration from play 2.3 to play 2.4

Tags: html, scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

I have migrated my project from play-slick 0.8 to play-slick 1.0 (https://github.com/playframework/play-slick)... that means changing play version from 2.3 to 2.4 and slick version from 2.1 to 3.0.

After some changes in my controllers I am now getting a compilation error in my templates:

> type mismatch; 
>     found : play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable (which expands to)   play.twirl.api.Html
>     required: String

This is my template 'createForm.scala.html'. The error references the first line inside the @main block, whatever it is  (in this case "Add fireman").

```
@(bomberoForm: Form[Bombero], categorias: Seq[(String, String)])(implicit flash: play.api.mvc.Flash, messages: Messages)

@import helper._

@main {

    <h1>Add fireman</h1>

    @form(routes.BomberosController.save) {
```

This is my 'main.html':

```
@(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Gestión de turnos</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css")">

        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")"/>

    </head>
    <body>

        <header class="topbar">
            <h1 class="fill">
                <a href="@routes.BomberosController.index()">
                    Gestión de turnos
                </a>
            </h1>
        </header>

        <section id="main">
            @content
        </section>

    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my controller:

```
class BomberosController @Inject() (val messagesApi: MessagesApi, bomberos: Bomberos)
  extends Controller with I18nSupport {

  /**
   * This result directly redirect to the bomberos management home.
   */
  val Home = Redirect(routes.BomberosController.list(0, 1, ""))

  /**
   * Describe the bombero form (used in both edit and create screens).
   */
  val bomberoForm: Form[Bombero] = Form(
    mapping(
      "matricula" -> number,
      "nombre" -> nonEmptyText,
      "apellidos" -> nonEmptyText,
      "categoria" -> number,
      "fechaDeIngreso" -> jodaLocalDate("dd/MM/yyyy"),
      "parque" -> nonEmptyText,
      "letra" -> nonEmptyText(1,1)
    )((m, n, a, c, f, p, letra) => Bombero(m, n, a, c, f, p, letra.head))
      ((b: Bombero) => Some(b.matricula, b.nombre, b.apellidos, b.categoria, b.fechaDeIngreso, b.parque, b.letra.toString))
  )

  def index = Action { Home }

  def list(page: Int, orderBy: Int, filter: String) = Action.async { implicit request =>
    for {
      bomberosList <- bomberos.list(page = page, orderBy = orderBy, filter =("%"+filter+"%"))
    } yield
      Ok(views.html.bomberos.list(bomberosList, orderBy, filter))
  }

  def create = Action.async { implicit request =>
    for (catOpts <- bomberos.categoriasOptions) yield
      Ok(views.html.bomberos.createForm(bomberoForm, catOpts))
  }
....
```

Any ideas why I am getting this error?

Comment: My guess is that your `main` invocation is referencing the default one created by the activator template (which has a string for the title as its first arg) rather than your own `main`, but without seeing the full structure it's hard to tell. Your code should otherwise compile.

Comment: That was the case! Thank you !!